# What is time complexity of using "not in list" in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, time-complexity, nested-for-loop

This is a program for finding missing number in a list containing elements from `1 to n` in python.

```
def reqfun(l):
    x=0
     //finding large no
    for i in l:
        if i>x:
            x=i
    for i in range(1,x):
        if i not in l:
            print("missing : ", i)
list=[9,4,3,8,5,6,2,7]
reqfun(list)
```

Is there any time complexity by using `not in` in `if statement` as it checks every element in the list. How does it works? Is it better than using a `nested loop` or is it same or is it worse. Can anyone help me understanding this?

Comment: This has *very* likely been answered already, but as far as I know, the time complexity of `x in set` is `O(1)` and `x in list` is `O(n)`. There is additional cost when converting a list to a set though, so it's only worth it if checking multiple times.

Comment: For your case, I'd just iterate through the sorted list which would be `O(log n)` I think? Your way right now is very inefficient and probably `O(n^2)`.

Comment: It's `O(n)`, according to Python's wiki entry on Time Complexity - https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity.

Comment: Bad idea to use a variable called `list` as you're obscuring the builtin `list` which will cause all sorts of other runtime errors if you try to use what should be the builtin `list`. I find a very helpful convention is for variable name for lists to end in `s` like `numbers`, then it's obvious what's happening when I want a for loop `for number in numbers:`